# \Cref (package cleveref) problem with subequations

Tags: numbering, cleveref

I found a bug with these three settings used together.
Basically, I need to use `subequations` for (only) one equation.
In this example, it is on page 1.

I also need to use `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` to number my equations.

Finally I use the package `cleverref` to get things like `Theorem 1` without
type `Theorem` myself.

Compile the code below, go to page 4 and click link there. It goes to page 1.
But it is expected to go to page 3.

If I comment out `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`, it is fine, but this style of numbering equations is not what I want.

If I don't use the package `cleveref` and just use `\ref` instead of `\Cref`,
it goes to page 3 which is correct. But I lose the advantage of using this package.

I need a solution to this problem but still to have the desired result (style of numbering, the advantage of `cleveref`...etc).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

This is a list of equations in page 1.
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a &= b \label{aaaa}  \\
a &= b \label{bbbb}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\newpage

This is an equation in page 2.
\begin{equation} \label{cccc}
 abcd
\end{equation}

\newpage

\section{Section 2}

This is section 2 in page 3.
\begin{equation} \label{dddd}
 abc
\end{equation}

\newpage

\Cref{dddd}. Click the link here will go to page 1, which is not
expected.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is no bug, but just the consequence of the way `hyperref` and `cleveref` changes the labels.

`\numberwithin{equation}{section}` must be done **before** `hyperref` and  `cleveref`, i.e. both packages are informed about this counting style.

The link to the second equation `abcd` works, because it's in the same first section, but after the section is updated, the information isn't. 
It's very convenient to compile on the console to see the warnings about `hyperref`'s name anchors.

General rule: `\numberwithin` and `\counterwithin` (from `chngcntr` package) should be placed **before** `hyperref` and `cleveref` are included.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

This is a list of equations in page 1.
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a &= b \label{aaaa}  \\
a &= b \label{bbbb}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\newpage

This is an equation in page 2.
\begin{equation} \label{cccc}
 abcd
\end{equation}

\newpage

\section{Section 2}

This is section 2 in page 3.
\begin{equation} \label{dddd}
 abc
\end{equation}

\newpage


\Cref{cccc}
\Cref{dddd}. Click the link here will go to page 1, which is not
expected.

\end{document}
```

Comment: So the problem is just the position of `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`?

Comment: @user565739: Yes, as I've explained at the top (right now)

Comment: Maybe not a bug, but surely a misfeature that, in my opinion should be fixed anyway: just as new counters should defined *after* `hyperref` has been loaded, changing their representation should too.

Comment: @egreg: Isn't that the `\theHcounter` stuff meant for? (Not desirable as well, I know) But the basic 'criminal' here is `cleveref`, in my point of view

Comment: 'criminal' is a bit harsh, no? I might accept `culprit'...though I reckon hyperref and amsmath are accessories to the crime :-) See my answer for details.

Comment: @TobyCubitt: That's why I wrote 'criminal' ;-) And which answer? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Save it for the judge ;-) My answer (currently) appears below, on this page. Probably you were just a bit too quick, and replied slightly before it appeared/I'd hit submit.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: should be fixed in the latest pre-release version (0.21) available from my web-site http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex.html

This one confounded me for a while, because `cleveref` steers well clear of the `hyperref` counter-mangling machinery and doesn't touch `\numberwithin` or the lower-level `\@addtoreset` at all. A bit of sleuthing in `.aux` files revealed the bug was worse than reported: using `subequations` anywhere in the document broke the hyperlink destinations of *all* subsequent equation environments, even ones that don't use subequations at all!

Turns out the problem was caused by `cleveref` doing some temporary `\@addtoreset`'s within subequations to get the clever referencing machinery to work there, naively assuming no one would mess with this low-level LaTeX kernel macro to make it do something more than adding a counter to a reset list. Unfortunately, `hyperref` messes with this low-level LaTeX kernel macro to make it do something more than adding a counter to a reset list. `amsmath` isn't blameless here, either. None of this would be necessary if its subequations implementation wasn't such a convoluted affair.

I've modified the `cleveref` code to use its own version of `\@addtoreset` which is always let to the vanilla kernel macro, even when `hyperref` is loaded.

Roll on LaTeX3... (naively hoping the LaTeX3 kernel and document classes will be designed with add-on packages in mind, so one doesn't have to create this kind of unholy mess of macro patch on top of macro patch!)