# IEEEtrantools breaks restated theorems (thm-restate)

Tags: theorems, cleveref, thmtools, xpatch, ieeetrantools

I really like this [**question/answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436280/36835) ("patched theorem defintion" in the minimal example) and I wanted to adapt it to my custom dissertation class file. However, I ran into some problems with the package `IEEEtrantools`, which I "need" to typeset some math.

Originally, the definition of my theorems was placed inside the `\AtEndPreamble` hook, although I don't remember why, it worked together with `IEEEtrantools`. But if the above Q/A is applied inside the hook, the patch has no effect. If I put it outside the hook, `IEEEtrantools` causes errors.

I could try to avoid `IEEEtrantools`, but I prefer not to. So can you identify what is causing the problem and may offer a solution?

Thank you in advance!

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}
%\RequirePackage{IEEEtrantools} % <==== breaks patched theorem defintion

%% patched theorem defintion ==============
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\thmt@restatable}% Edit \thmt@restatable
{\csname #2\@xa\endcsname\ifx\@nx#1\@nx\else[{#1}]\fi}% Replace this code
{\ifthmt@thisistheone\csname #2\@xa\endcsname\ifx\@nx#1\@nx\else[{#1}]\fi\else\csname #2\@xa\endcsname\fi}% with this code
{}{} % execute code for success/failure instances
\makeatother
%% ========================================

\AtEndPreamble{     
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[sort&compress]{cleveref}
    
    % <=== theorem definition could be moved here and originally was here, but then the patch does not work.
}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{restatable}[\S\ref{SectionNumber}]{thm}{TheoremName}
theorem contents
\end{restatable}

\section{Some Section}
\label{SectionNumber}

\TheoremName*

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem between `cleveref` and subequations from some time. See the comments of
@Toby Cubitt done in

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375140/161015

While `cleveref` code was modified to use its own version of `\@addtoreset` it seem that still fails when `IEEEtrantools` is loaded.

A patch might skip the compilation error, for example by making `IEEEsubequation` slave to `equation` instead of `subequation` ( in `\cref@addtoreset{IEEEsubequation}{subequation}`) but I think it is best to wait for better fix from the developer.